# Can't enable Anonymous Access - 2010 Foundations

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, anonymous-authentication

I have setup a Sharepoint Foundations 2010 server on a fresh install of Windows Server 2012R2 in a VM so I could mess around with Sharepoint, though I'm stuck on what I consider to be a pretty basic feature: Anonymous Access.

Every guide that I've found says the same thing, which I'll briefly reiterate:

- Go to Central administration > Manage web applications, select the
  'Sharepoint - 80' row, click 'Authentication Providers', click
  'Default', check off 'Enable anonymous access' and click save.
- Click 'Anonymous Policy', select 'None' for 'Anonymous Policy'
  and click save.
- Site Actions > Site Settings > Site Permissions and click the
  'Anonymous Access' button.

Though I don't have a button for that, which according to what I've read means I haven't checked the 'Enable anonymous access' despite it being enabled. If I go to /_layouts/setanon.aspx, the options are all grayed out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you try with Server 2012, as SharePoint 2013 does not support Server 2012 R2.

Comment: did you say you select "None"..Click 'Anonymous Policy', select 'None' for 'Anonymous User Policy' and click save."
you should select from 1st and 2nd options.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the "Anonymous Policy" button. Everything else that I've tried works, so unless I really have to, I won't be downgrading to 2008 or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable anonymous access like your above steps. You must create a new web application with the option **"Allow Anonymous" is yes.** Once the web application is created. You can configure the anonymous access by your steps in above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I didn't get the Anonymous Access button, though once I went to /_layouts/setanon.aspx again, the options weren't grayed out and I was able to make the changes.